# Angular - detect changed to the same value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller and a directive. In the directive there is array of data from the controller.
When a button from the directive is clicked I want the controller to update the data.
So the button is clicked, I show a busy indicator and when the controller finishes to update the data I want to hide the busy indicator. My problem is that some times the data stays the same so the "watchCollection" function is not triggered.

Bottom line, I'm looking for a solution that will allow the controller to tell the directive that he has finished the update.

** Another solution I thought of is adding a boolean for "updating". The directive will change it to true and the controller will change it to false when it is finished. But the problem again is that in some cases the value of "updating" is changed back to false before the digest cycle is started detects that is was changed to true.

The directive looks something like this:

Directive:

```
{
scope: {
        arrayData: "=",
        onChangeData: "&"
},

controller: function($scope){
     $scope.buttonClicked : function(){
         // show busy indicator
         $scope.onChangeData();
     }
}

link: function preLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watchCollection('arrayData', function (value) {
          // hide busy indicator
   });
}
}
```

Comment: Can please tell us onChangeData() are you again rebuilding the arrayData or manipulating the existing one.

Comment: Sometimes it's the same reference (the same array object)and sometimes it's a new object.

Comment: Where is the array object retrieved from? A server or -? You could find a way of including the indicator in some kind of callback.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean - the array sometimes comes from the server and in other cases not.

Comment: Well, what I was basically asking is what happens in `$scope.buttonClicked`? Surely, if there is no change, then there is no need to show a busy indicator. However, if there is a delay in determining if the array object actually changed, what causes the delay?

Comment: The busy is inside the directive so the flow is that the directive shows the busy and only then tells the controller (not his controller - but the father controller) to update the data. When the directive shows the busy it doesn't know if the collection is going to change. The directive expects the controller to tell him when it finishes the update. How does the controller can communicate with the directive? I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is by returning a promise for `onChangeData` like

```
$scope.onChangeData=function() {
   var defer=$q.defer();
   //process data
   //resolve defer
   return defer.promise;
}
```

Then in your directive controller do

```
$scope.onChangeData().then(function() {
    //stop animation
});
```

Comment: But then the user of my directive should be aware of the fact that he has to return a promise... it this a common solution?

Comment: So I decided to use something similar to your suggestion. I created the defer inside "buttonClicked" and passed the defer to the controller - something like passing a callback.